# Android Studio with grid view but can change width (like Excel)

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to make a view like I can see in Excel?

Also, I heard grid view is being abandoned and recycler view is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use recyclerView for make a grid. But like excel look you need some effect or border. recyclerview gives you grid without any border.